# Backbone.undo.js not tracking my second span and doesn't save start value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a little app where I want to edit *spans* by clicking them. I have two spans but when i edit second span, the first one automaticly change to the same value as the second one. I also cannot change to first value of spans, because first value by clicking undo is *foo*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Backbone.Undo sample</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            line-height: 140%;
        }

        #centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            margin-top: -120px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol id="centered">
        <li>
            <span type="text" id="input" value="foo">span1 </span>
            <button id="set">set</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span type="text" id="input2" value="foo">span2 </span>
            <button id="Button1">set</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="undo">undo</button>
            <button id="redo">redo</button>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="../Backbone.Undo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var model = new Backbone.Model({ "text": "foo" }),
            View = Backbone.View.extend({
                initialize: function () {
                    // If the model's text changes, update the view
                    this.model.on("change:text", function (model, text, options) {
                        if (text != this.$el.text()) {
                            this.$el.text(text);
                        }
                    }, this);
                }
            })
            view = new View({
                model: model,
                el: $("#input")
            })
            // Now: The undo/redo part 
            var undoManager = new Backbone.UndoManager;
            undoManager.register(model);
            undoManager.startTracking();

            $("#undo").on("click", function () {
                undoManager.undo();
            })
            $("#redo").on("click", function () {
                undoManager.redo();
            })
            $("#input").on("click", function () {
                var element = document.getElementById("input");
                element.innerHTML = prompt("#input", element.innerHTML);
                model.set("text", $("#input").text());
            })
            $("#input2").on("click", function () {
                var element = document.getElementById("input2");
                element.innerHTML = prompt("#input2", element.innerHTML);
                model.set("text", $("#input2").text());
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you are using 1 model and 1 view but you want them to act independently. So when you click span2 you are still setting the same model which is why they both change.

For this i would use seperate model and seperate views for the both spans like this

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    "text": "span1"
});
var model2 = new Backbone.Model({
    "text": "span2"
});
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // If the model's text changes, update the view
        this.model.on("change:text", function (model, text, options) {
            if (text != this.$el.text()) {
                this.$el.text(text);
            }
        }, this);
    }
});
var view1 = new View({
    model: model,
    el: $("#input")
});

var view2 = new View({
    model: model2,
    el: $("#input2")
});
```

then register your other model in the undo register

```
// Now: The undo/redo part 
var undoManager = new Backbone.UndoManager;
undoManager.register(model);
undoManager.register(model2);
undoManager.startTracking();
```

and finally change your click handler on span2 to edit the new model

```
$("#input2").on("click", function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("input2");
    element.innerHTML = prompt("#input2", element.innerHTML);
    model2.set("text", $("#input2").text());
})
```

[here is a fiddle with it all together](http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/2vx00s4b/)

You can also be taking advantage of backbone more by having your view handle the events rather that doing this outside. here is an example

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // If the model's text changes, update the view
        this.model.on("change:text", function (model, text, options) {
            if (text != this.$el.text()) {
                this.$el.text(text);
            }
        }, this);
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'editValue'
    },
    editValue: function () {
        var data = prompt("#input2", this.model.get("text"));
        if(data)
        {
            this.model.set("text", data);
        }
    }
    });
```

now the view handles this change to the model and we also don;t have to get data from the html we keep it in the model at all times. here is an updated fiddle showing this technique http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/2vx00s4b/9/

---

A More Backboney approach making use of a template for each model, a collection to hold your models and then a view for showing the collection and a view for showing each model. I have tried to add comments to show what the different parts are doing, ask if you want anything cleared up

[Fiddle of this example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/ky8z30fv/)

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/template" id="model-template">
    <span type="text" class="input" value="foo"><%= text %></span>
        <button class="remove">remove</button>
</script>
<div id="centered">
    <ol id="collection-hook"> 
    </ol>
    <button id="undo">undo</button>
    <button id="redo">redo</button>
    <button id="add">add</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: "Click To Edit Text"
    }
});
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model
});

var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "model",

    //get the template and cache it for future use
    template:_.template($('#model-template').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        // If the model's text changes, update the view
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change:text", this.render, this);
        //if the model is removed from the collection close this view
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.close, this);
    },

    //events this view will be listening for
    events: {
        'click span.input': 'editValue',
        'click button.remove': 'removeModel',
    },

    //get the models collection from it's self and tell the collection to remove the model
    removeModel: function() {
        this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
    },

    //ensure model and all events are destroyed and remove this view from the DOM
    close: function() {
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
        this.stopListening();
    },

    //render this view with the models data
    render: function() {

        //attach the generated template to this views $el
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            text: this.model.get("text")
        }));

        //return this view so collection view can decided where to place it on the DOM
        return this;
    },

    editValue: function() {
        var data = prompt("Change text", this.model.get("text"));
        if (data) {
            this.model.set("text", data);
        }
    }
});

var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#centered"),
    //store a refrence to where you would like to add your models
    collectinoHook: $("#collection-hook", this.$el),

    initialize: function() {
        this.undoManager = new Backbone.UndoManager;

        this.undoManager.startTracking();

        //when ever a new model is added to the collection call the function
        //to render it
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderOne, this);

    },

    events: {
        'click #add': 'addModel',
        'click #redo': 'redo',
        'click #undo': 'undo',
    },

    //render the collection items one at a time
    renderOne: function(model) {
        this.undoManager.register(model);
        //create a new view using this model
        var view = new ModelView({
            model: model
        });

        //append the new view to you list
        this.collectinoHook.append(view.render().el);
    },

    //use this to render the view with existing models in the collection
    render: function() {
        //clear the current views that have been rendered not the cleanest method as
        //those views will still exist but this is a quick example
        this.collectinoHook.html('');
        this.collection.each(_.bind(function(model) {
            this.renderOne(model);
        },this));
    },


    undo: function() {
        this.undoManager.undo();
    },
    redo: function() {
        this.undoManager.redo();
    },
    addModel: function() {

        //create a new model and add it to the collection
        var model = new Model();
        this.collection.add(model);
    },

});

var collection = new Collection();
var collectionView = new CollectionView({
    collection: collection
});
```

Comment: Tank you. How can i manage to create dynamicly my models depence how many spans i have? I want to be able to edit all spans and easly add new ones.

Comment: so for this you would need to start making use of templates (to hold the markup for your model), collections (to hold all your models) and using one view as your model view and another as your collection view. Then in the collection view you can add some handlers linked to buttons to add a new model. There can be lots of examples of this found in the guise of ToDo app tutorials, this is where i started when learning backbone

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to make **"text"** position in my model equal to equivalent of it's span **.text()**?

I mean if i have `<span type="text" id="input" value="foo">example</span>` i want to have `var model = new Backbone.Model({
    "text": "span1" // here my $("#input").text()
});`

Comment: It should be the other way round, your data should tell the html what to display. If you look into templates when you render a span you can tell it to take the value of text

Comment: @Volz ive updated my answer with a quick example of what i was talking about by making use of the full set of backbone features

Comment: wow that undo plugin is really good, it undoes the removal of the models from the collection as well as the model changes. cool.